How is lodash turning this into boolean[]?
I am trying to write a function in typescript which validates that an object has certain properties and I got stuck at the very beginning do keys xyz exist? I tried to do that with the following code:
import _ from 'lodash/fp'; 

type Pred = (o: Object) => boolean

const required_keys: Pred[] = _.map(_.has,['id','field1'])
const validate: Pred = _.overEvery(required_keys)

I expected that type of required_keys would be Pred[] but typescript LSP tells me it is boolean[]. I expected that after we apply one argument to _.has I still have to apply another one the object that that is being tested.
Am I wrong or is it LSP, and how can LSP and I come to an agreement?

Seems like a bug with the typings, _.map(_.has,['id','field1']) indeed produces an array of predicates. For some reason, it seems to think that has was fully applied which isn't the case.

By passing a 1-ary lambda (i.e. a function with a single parameter) explicitly, the correct type can be inferred:
const required_keys: Pred[] = _.map(p => _.has(p), ['id', 'field1']);
const validate: Pred = _.overEvery(required_keys);

I can see many overloads of both functions in the type definitions. It looks like the compiler has trouble figuring out which ones apply.
The canonical way with lodash/fp – as I understood it – would be _.map(_.has)(['id', 'field1']), but this doesn't solve your initial problem nor does it work with an explicit lambda parameter because its type would be inferred as unknown.
